# Asyncio + Celery: Distribute tasks

Tags: python-3.x, celery, celery-task, python-asyncio

I'm using Celery and asyncio and I have some CPU bound function.

My issue is:
When I'm running a single task, it takes X seconds. When I'm trying to run 10 tasks it takes approximately 10X seconds.

The current implementation looks similar to:

```
job = group(custom_func.s(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5) for param3, param4 in data)
job_result = job.apply_async()
job_result.get()


@celery_app.task
def custom_func(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    coro = doing_some_cpu_bound_things()
    result = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    loop.close()
    return result
```

After googling possible solutions, I've found this question:
[Celery parallel distributed task with multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916413/celery-parallel-distributed-task-with-multiprocessing)

But I'm not sure if this is the root cause of my issue and how to use it properly in my case.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding more concurrency to celery worker and check.

Comment: @sp1rs Do you mean to add more celery workers?

Comment: Try all the combinations.

Comment: @sp1rs, which combinations do you mean?

Comment: Run couple of worker with concurrency has 2/3.